# Long command in terminal.app cause a bug

Tags: terminal, bash, bug

If I am in the last line of Terminal.app and enter a long command, it does not create new line, but instead overwrites the same line.

How can I solve this bug?

[image: Terminal.app Screenshot with stacked command lines]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a hunch that this is primarily caused by your accented characters (çã) in your directory name, because this is not a problem by default:

[image: Terminal.app multi-line screenshot]

Special characters, unprintable or otherwise, frequently cause problems with classic terminals / shells.

Try opening a new terminal tab/window, and see if this problem occurs immediately, or if it doesn't occur until after you enter a directory with special characters.

Comment: Wow.. You are correct.. You fix the bug!!! I have to rename the folder.